# HTML input element child

Tags: html, css

I have a Three floating INPUTS which are moving according to screen width, meaning they can either be side by side or on top of each other.

For each element, I need to place a text position absolutely according to the INPUT element. 
I am aware of position:relative (for the father element) and position:absolute for the child element (text).

My problem, and likely a noobish one. How do I make a child element for an `<input>` element (since it doesn't have a closing tag)?

Code Example:

```
<input class="floating element" style="position:relative;">
<section class="text_for_floating_element" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;">
```

In the above example, the `<section>` element is NOT a child of the `<input>` element, hence the `<section>` element will get positioned according to the closest father, and not the required element. How do I make the `<section>` element a child of the `<input>` element?

Comment: does one truly need to be the child of the other? or could they both be children of a `<div>` element

Comment: `<input>` cannot have children. I suggest wrapping the two elements in a container element.

Comment: Thats what i thought too :( was hoping to avoid that. Thank you everyone

Comment: What's the text that you have to position?

Comment: @DavidThomas > simple text modified using css

Comment: But what relation does it have to the input element? Is it a label..?

Comment: @DavidThomas > Yes, it is a label that simply states what the input picture means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the associated text is 'a label that simply states what the input picture means,' I'd suggest using a `label` element, and wrapping the `input` inside of that element:

```
<label>Guidance relating to input element:
    <input />
</label>
```

With the CSS:

```
label {
    width: 30%; /* or whatever... */
    float: left;
}

label input {
    display: block;
}
```

[Representative JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eUMp4/).